# Beautifulsoup find_all does not find all tags Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to scrape the web page specifically [this web page](https://www.toysrus.fi/nallet-ja-pehmolelut/interaktiiviset-pehmolelut) for example. I am trying to scrape the product names but somehow my find_all method doesn't work properly and not finding all tags I specified.

So here is what I am doing

```
from bs4 import BeatifulSoup

url = 'https://www.toysrus.fi/nallet-ja-pehmolelut/interaktiiviset-pehmolelut'
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html.parser')
print(len(soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'inner-wrapper'})))
```

The length of the `class='inner-wrapper'` is actually 4 in the specified page but it finds only 1. Please guide in scraping the product names from the web page and how can I get correct number of tags of `div` having `class'inner-wrapper'`. Thanks.

Comment: There is only one `inner-wrapper` class. There are another two in a javascript section, which won't be executed by `request` or `BeautifulSoup`, and aren't applied to the DOM.

Comment: So how can I extract that product name information using BeautifulSoup ? Or do I have to use something else ?

Comment: not necesserely with BeatifulSoup only , you might be able evaluate somehow javascript or figure out how pull product list

Comment: This site uses JS for populating its content. In order to scrape info about products, you need to use either Selenium or simulate ajax request to the site.

Comment: Now I am using selenium and this is my code `browser = browser.get('https://www.toysrus.fi/nallet-ja-pehmolelut/interaktiiviset-pehmolelut')` after initializing `browser=webdriver.Chrome()`. It opens the page in chrome but when I print on console it returns `None`

Comment: you just need to get your products form browser

Comment: add get_source() . If still not evaluated js, try click on page, wait a sec, etc. You should also able to target the divs you need from selenium

Answer (score 0):

Beatiful soup only finds proper html divs tags, those happened to be inside of scripts are ignored. Regretfully Beautiful soup does not evaluates scripts. 
Just open the HTML code, you will see one HTML div of class, and bunch of scripts/js-templates like below

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="product-list-skuid-template">
  <div class="product-list-component type-{{:TemplateInfo.type}} outer-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <ul class="product-list-container">
        {{for Data}} {{include tmpl="#product-template"/}} {{/for}}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{!-- SHADOW --}} {{if TemplateInfo.divider=='roundshadow'}}
  <div class="round-shadow"></div>
  {{else TemplateInfo.divider=='simple'}}
  <hr /> {{/if}}
</script>
```